# Expire Cache for action caching with custom cache_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, action-caching

I have implemented the action caching in rails 3.2 with following syntax

```
 caches_action :show, { 
 :unless => proc {|c| 
  current_user.present? || @current_member.present? || @is_crawler 
  },   :cache_path => proc { |controller| 
   controller.params.merge(:device => "#{device_type.to_s}")}}
```

But However I want the action cache to expire for all versions of the device type whenever the caching is updated.
I am using the following syntax in controller.
`expire_action( :action => :show)`

Sadly enough the above code does not work as intended. Quite frankly I am new to using caching and any help is much appreciated.

Comment: first of all, try to be more explicit when you ask questions or describe your problem. "does not work as intended" is a pretty bad error description. what was your intention and how did the result diverge from it?

Comment: Hmm sorry if I was not descriptive enough. When calling the update action in the controller i am using `expire_action(:action => :show)` But this does not clear the cache and still serves the cached version.

Comment: you need to match whatever is part of the cache-path to clear it. i don't know if you can use a regular expression or something like that, otherwise, use a custom cache sweeper. all in all, action-caching is considered deprecated, use an in-memory cache like memcached to do such things.

Comment: @phoet Thanks for the help. I will post the answer on how I got it working.